# Display Specific Line from Notepad in List Box VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am completely new to VB.net and have only been learning in for a few weeks I am doing a project where i need to make an EPOS systems using notepad as a data base. I am able to make the values of the buttons appear in the list box, however I have numerous buttons all with different values but only the first value in the text box is appearing each time a different button is pressed. E.G When Heineken button pressed "Heineken €5.00" is displayed when Guiness button pressed "Heineken €5.00" is displayed

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Imports System.IO 

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnHeineken_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHeineken.Click
        Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("DATABASE.txt")
        'File DATABASE.TXT is the the debug folder

        Dim name As String

        Dim stock, price As Double
        name = sr.ReadLine

        stock = CDbl(sr.ReadLine)

        price = CDbl(sr.ReadLine)

        lstBox.Items.Add(name & "" & FormatCurrency(price))
        name = sr.ReadLine

    End Sub

Private Sub BtnGuiness_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGuiness.Click
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("DATABASE.txt")
    'File DATABASE.TXT is the the debug folder

    Dim name As String

    Dim stock, price As Double
    name = sr.ReadLine

    stock = CDbl(sr.ReadLine)

    price = CDbl(sr.ReadLine)

    lstBox.Items.Add(name & "" & FormatCurrency(price))
    name = sr.ReadLine
End Sub
```

DATBASE.txt

Heineken,
5.00,
20,
Guiness,
4.50,
50,
Bulmers,
5.00,
25,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notepad database in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670892/notepad-database-in-vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` function to get all data in an string array. You can then use array index to find a specific line.

Note: Your text file must contain new-line characters after each item. The text you have posted doesn't appear to have that.

So for example:

```
Private Sub BtnGuiness_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGuiness.Click
    Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("DATABASE.txt")
    dim Parts = lines(1).Split(","c) '1 means 2nd line
    Dim name As String
    Dim stock, price As Double
    name = Parts(0)
    stock = CDbl(Parts(1))
    price = CDbl(Parts(2))

    lstBox.Items.Add(name & "" & FormatCurrency(price))
End Sub
```

This assumes that the text file has these contents:

```
Heineken, 5.00, 20
Guiness, 4.50, 50 
Bulmers, 5.00, 25
```

(Notice `ENTER` key at the end of each line)

This is just the basic concept. In real world we do not do things this way. Plus there are some checks that should be placed in proper locations to avoid exceptions resulting from malformed input text. I've skipped all that stuff for brevity.